# How to retrieve Property names in Gstreamer

Tags: c++, plugins, gstreamer

I want to retrieve Element Property names of GstElement in C++. gst-inspect writes all of the details about plugin.

I could retrieve factory and plugin details like these on code. 

Factory Details: 
Plugin Details:

By writing,
gst_plugin_feature_get_name (GST_PLUGIN_FEATURE (factory)),
             gst_element_factory_get_metadata (factory, GST_ELEMENT_METADATA_KLASS),
             gst_element_factory_get_metadata (factory, GST_ELEMENT_METADATA_DESCRIPTION),
             gst_element_factory_get_metadata (factory, GST_ELEMENT_METADATA_LONGNAME));

However, I couldn't find any functions about property details (Element Properties Section) in Gstreamer.

I expect C++ code like
gst_plugin_feature_get_name (GST_PLUGIN_FEATURE (factory)),
             gst_element_factory_get_metadata (factory, GST_ELEMENT_METADATA_KLASS),
             gst_element_factory_get_metadata (factory, GST_ELEMENT_METADATA_DESCRIPTION),
             gst_element_factory_get_metadata (factory, GST_ELEMENT_METADATA_LONGNAME));
that.

I want to retrieve all of the property names of GstElement.
For instance, for openh264enc 
bitrate, complexity, gop-size and etc.

Comment: Pretty sure you will find your answer when checking the code of the `gst-inspect-1.0` tool: https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/blob/master/tools/gst-inspect.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that after I post the question... However, as it may be useful to other people I am posting the answer.

```
GObjectClass* objClass = G_OBJECT_GET_CLASS(*element);
guint n_props;
GParamSpec** props;
props = g_object_class_list_properties(objClass,&n_props);

if(objClass != nullptr){
    if(props != nullptr){
        for (guint i = 0; i < n_props; i++) {
            if(props[i] != nullptr)
                qInfo() << props[i]->name;
        }
    }else{
        qWarning() << "Element props are NULL!";
    }
}else{
    qWarning() << "Obj Class is NULL!";
}
```